# Remove context menu options in Files, Ubuntu Gnome 16.04

Tags: 16.04, nautilus, context-menu

I would like to remove the E-mail and Compress options from the context menu of Files (nautilus) in Ubuntu Gnome 16.04.

Any idea which file/s I would need to edit and it's location?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Some of the right-click options in Files (nautilus) are determined by systemwide nautilus extensions, and may indeed be removed by removing that extension.

To remove the **"E-mail" option**:

```
sudo apt remove nautilus-sendto
```

Removing the **"Compress" option** is less obvious. This comes installed with the file compression utility file-roller. You will remove the option with the following command, but you also will remove the file compression utility file-roller:

```
sudo apt remove file-roller
```

If you want to remove only the option, but keep the application file-roller, then you need to resort to an unsupported hack: rename (or delete) the file `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/nautilus/extensions-3.0/libnautilus-fileroller.so'.

```
sudo mv /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/nautilus/extensions-3.0/libnautilus-fileroller.so /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/nautilus/extensions-3.0/libnautilus-fileroller.so.old
```

To restore, just switch the two file paths.

This is "unsupported", because you operate out of the packet management at the file level. An upgrade in file-roller will put the file back, so you then will need to repeat the process.